# H and K are normal subgroups of relatively prime order. Prove that HK is abelian if H and K are abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know I need to prove $(hk)(h'k') = (h'k')(hk)$. But I'm a bit lost as to how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$ implies $H \cap K = \{e\}$ ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20258/what-happens-when-the-order-of-two-finite-subgroups-are-relatively-prime)). Given that H and K are normal subgroups, it can be seen that $hk=kh$ for all $k \in K$ and $h \in H$. In particular, $h k h^{-1} \in K$ and $k h^{-1} k^{-1} \in H$ imply $(h k h^{-1}) k^{-1} = h (k h^{-1} k^{-1})\in H \cap K = \{e\}$. Therefore, $hk=kh$ for all $k \in K$ and $h \in H$ (this proposition can be found in many standard textbooks either as an exercise or an independent lemma).

Given that $hk=kh$ for all $k \in K$ and $h \in H$, the successive application of this property, associativity and commutativity of the elements of K and H to $(hk)(h'k')=(h'k')(hk)$ yields the desired result.